# ASP.NET Impersonation design

Tags: asp.net

This is my ASP.NET authentication operation.

```
    private void LoginButton_Click(Object sender,
                       EventArgs e)
    {
        string userName = txtUserName.Value;
        string password = txtUserPass.Value;

        if (ValidateUser(txtUserName.Value, txtUserPass.Value))
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket tkt;
            string cookiestr;
            HttpCookie ck;
            tkt = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, txtUserName.Value, DateTime.Now,
                                                DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(3), chkPersistCookie.Checked,
                                                userName + "@ticket");
            cookiestr = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(tkt);
            ck = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, cookiestr);
            if (chkPersistCookie.Checked)
                ck.Expires = tkt.Expiration;
            ck.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath;
            Response.Cookies.Add(ck);

            string strRedirect;
            strRedirect = Request["ReturnUrl"];
            if (strRedirect == null)
                strRedirect = "MyAccount.aspx";
            Response.Redirect(strRedirect, true);
        }
        else
            Response.Redirect("logon.aspx", true);

    }
```

I have User table in my db where all credentials are saved. Using `ValidateUser` method I am doing credentials validation. Also I have three type of users: Member, Moderator and Administrator. Each type of members has unique functionality. Lets say I have A, B and C T-SQL stored inside in my db.

What should I to to let for:

*Member* execute only A query.

*Moderator* execute A and B.

*Administrator* execute A,B and C.

Of course, I can manage execution from Web app, but I am not sure how safe it is. Technically I can execute similar query outside of App, which gives access to all db data. I want somehow combine Web App login and Db access as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If these queries are going to come from the web app, I think you would want to manage the code side that invokes the procedures..  you could maintain a list of urls in your database, assign roles, and give these roles access to specific urls.  These urls would dictate what queries a user could execute...

then in your code you could assign custom attributes to limit access to them....

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can manage them from Web app, but I am not sure how safe it is. Technically I can execute similar query outside of App, which gives access to all data. I want somehow combine Web App login and Db access as well.

Comment: Typically, you have a web app that interacts with a DB and uses a user, typically a power user, capable of executing all the required queries that the web app needs to execute, regardless of the web user context.  The web app then manages an authentication provider that will limit users ability execute queries on the DB according to business requirements...

Comment: I know a technique used commonly for intranet based sites, is to use integrated security.  This is where a user will log on to site with their Windows log on credentials.  Then any queries that hit the database will show up as a specific window identity, and there security and permissions will persist.

Comment: That's true. I can restrict access of execution on App lvl. But what if bad guy will create a new app and execute Administrators SQL statement straight from his application. Did you get an idea? How database know, which query it should limit if authentication happend before that?

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647396.aspx

Comment: this is Windows Impersonation, I am not under company domain, plus a lot of my users under Unix. So I guess is not going to work for me.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't be more help to you. I think the management of users on the app level is your best bet.  I don't think users who are creating apps should ever be anyone other then an adminstrator user anyway (and if they can be, I would reevaluate the type of commands the can issue while creating apps) , so i don't think you would ever have the issue where a 'bad user' would create and execute malicious code.